# Spreadsheet or script properties for simple index in Google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm programming a Google apps script store for tiddliwiki ([tiddlywiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com).com). It receives files and store them within Google Drive. It never overwrites any file, it just creates a new one on every upload. For performance reasons I want to maintain an index of the latest version of each file and its ID. Currently I'm using properties service to achieve this. When a file is uploaded, I store its Name:ID. That way retrieving a file by name does not require to search in the full folder neither check what is the latest version. I'm worried about how many entries can I store on the script properties store. I'm thinking about using a spreadsheet for save the index, but I don't know what is the difference in terms of performance compared to the properties service.

Here is the question: can I stick to properties service to achieve this task or should I switch to google spreadsheets? Will the performance be much worse? Any alternative for the index?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Since this will store only a few hundred of entries, what about using a JSON file as index. Will take it much time to load the text and parse it?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the amount of files you're expecting. For a few thousand files, the Property service might do and is surely easier to use than a Spreadsheet, but it has a tighter [limitation of 500kb](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) per store.

If you think you'll have more files, than it's probably best not to index at all, and do a fast Google Drive search to retrieve your latest file. The [search criteria](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) can be very specific and fast (filter by title only or any timestamp criteria). I think it'll be much less trouble in your script (than trying to build/fit a big index into memory, etc).

Comment: Hello Henrique. This is very cool but it requires the use of the Drive API, which is far away from a simple GAS script. Currently my script acts as the server. If I understand well, your proposal is to switch to google drive API and leave alone the idea of using google apps script because there is no need of more server than google API. Do you mean that?

Comment: Not really, having a Google Apps Script allows you to use the Drive API to access files that only you have access (see menu Library > Advanced Google Services). Hiding this "implementation detail" from the site accessing your script. But if you can share your folder with the users of you site (and they have Google Accounts), then you can skip Apps Script entirely, which is not a bad idea (at least performance wise).

Comment: Hello Henrique. The problem is that my users access from a client side JavaScript application. Ideally I would prefer the end user uploading files to their own google drives. But the google drive JavaScript API has problems with authentication process,or that is what I understood from my investigation. Do you know if I can use google apps script as just an identification platform and then make the rest of the request 100% client side ? Thank you

Comment: If you can't authenticate your users using a Google+ sign in button (which is much preferred), you could send your oAuth token from the Apps Script to your Javascript app, but that's overly insecure. Even if you create an account just for that. With the [Drive token](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes) one can do nearly anything in your Drive (e.g. read or delete any/all files)

Comment: Henrique, thank you very much for all your help. I checked Google developers guide and it's a new thing called  advanced services. With this you can make the query you proposed initially. Reading the description there is nothing that allows you to pick the last version of a file. So I have to get all the files and for those ones with the same name check which has the latest modification date. This can be definitively fast when you just need one file, but not for listing all the files in a folder I'm afraid.